# Photovoltaic cell creation

Tags: capacitor, photodiode

In order to create a photovoltaic cell all I need is a photodiode connected parallel to a capacitor right?

Comment: [This is a photovoltaic cell.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell)  They are used to generate power.  A photodiode and a capacitor would be some kind if photodetector.

Comment: What are you trying to build?

Comment: JRE we have to store somewhere current dont we?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: To store the photocurrent.A capacitor will do the job.

Comment: Why do you want to store the photocurrent?  What task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I dont want to power leds during day time because I have the sun giving me light.I do want light when the sun cant give me any.

Comment: You want to use a photodiode to turn your lights on and off according to the amount of light the photodiode detects.

Comment: Or do you want to store energy from the sun to light your LEDs in the dark

Comment: I want to have light in the dark by storing energy from the sun.

Comment: Then a diode and a capacitor will not work.  You need a solar cell and a rechargeable battery.  The solar cell charges then battery in the sunlight, and the battery powers the LEDs in the dark.

Comment: The amount of energy you can collect depends on the area illuminated by the sun and the length of time it is lit.  The area of a photodiode is too small to be useful.

Comment: True since while charging the capacitor the photodiode will become reverse biased.

Comment: A regular capacitor can't store enough energy.  A supercapacitor might be able to, but the typical solution is a photovoltaic cell (**not** a photodiode) and a rechargeable battery.

Comment: What about the diode becoming reverse biased limiting the diffused electrons and holes?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do, you should use a [photovoltaic cell (also known as a solar cell.)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-bsg/AM-5412CAR/869-1007-ND/2165192)

The one in the link looks like this:

[image]

That's an AM5412.  According to its [datasheet](https://panasonic.co.jp/ls/psam/en/products/pdf/Catalog_Amorton_ENG.pdf) it can produce 93 milliwatts.  That's 36 milliamperes at 2.6 volts.  It is a solar cell.

[image]

[This is a photodiode.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/PD333-3B-H0-L2/1080-1142-ND/2675633)

It looks like this:

[image]

According to its [datasheet](http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/PD333-3B-H0-L2.pdf) it can produce upto 35 microamperes of current at a maximum voltage of 0.39 volts.

[image]

If you could get maximum current and maximum voltage at the same time, that would be about 14 microwatts.

Lets say you want to drive a 3.3 volt LED at 20 milliamperes for 1 hour.  Energy:

$$3.3V \times 0.02 amperes \times 3600 seconds = 237.6 joules $$

The solar cell will need \$\frac{237.6}{0.093} = 2555 seconds\$ to collect the required energy.

The photo diode would need something on the order of 7000 times longer.

This is why you use photovoltaic cells instead of photodiodes.

[A 1F super capacitor charged to 3.3 volts contains 5.4 joules of energy.](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/eng/electronics/capacitor_energy)

To hold the required 237 joules of energy to light your LED for one hour, you would need 44 [1 farad supercapacitors.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet/FT0H105ZF/399-10810-ND/4290876)

They look like this:

[image]

They cost about four dollars each.

Or, you buy a couple of rechargeable NiMh cells that have far more capacity than all your supercapacitors together.  That might cost you 2 dollars.

That's why you use batteries instead of capacitors.

All of that ignores losses that will occur in charging your storage system, in regulating the current, and preventing your battery from backfeeding the solar cell when it's dark.